# Slicing and Setting Values in Pandas, with a composite of position and labels

Tags: pandas

I want to set a value in a specific cell in a `pandas dataFrame`.

I know which position the row is in (I can even get the row by using `df.iloc[i]`, for example), and I know the name of the column, but I can't work out how to select the cell so that I can set a value to it.

```
df.loc[i,'columnName']=val
```

won't work because I want the row in position `i`, not labelled with index `i`. Also

```
df.iloc[i, 'columnName'] = val
```

obviously doesn't like being given a column name. So, short of converting to a dict and back, how do I go about this? Help very much appreciated, as I can't find anything that helps me in the `pandas` documentation.

Comment: try `df.ix[i, 'columnName'] = val`

Comment: Gives a key error of `i`, I think because `i` isn't in the index labels?

Comment: that shouldn't fail, try `df['columnName'].iloc[i] = val`

Comment: `ix` looks for labels rather than positions when the indices are integers.

Comment: Yes that works great, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ix` to set a specific cell:

```
In [209]:
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,3), columns=list('abc'))
df

Out[209]:
          a         b         c
0  1.366340  1.643899 -0.264142
1  0.052825  0.363385  0.024520
2  0.526718 -0.230459  1.481025
3  1.068833 -0.558976  0.812986
4  0.208232  0.405090  0.704971

In [210]:
df.ix[1,'b'] = 0
df

Out[210]:
          a         b         c
0  1.366340  1.643899 -0.264142
1  0.052825  0.000000  0.024520
2  0.526718 -0.230459  1.481025
3  1.068833 -0.558976  0.812986
4  0.208232  0.405090  0.704971
```

You can also call `iloc` on the col of interest:

```
In [211]:
df['b'].iloc[2] = 0
df

Out[211]:
          a         b         c
0  1.366340  1.643899 -0.264142
1  0.052825  0.000000  0.024520
2  0.526718  0.000000  1.481025
3  1.068833 -0.558976  0.812986
4  0.208232  0.405090  0.704971
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the position of the column with get_loc:

```
df.iloc[i, df.columns.get_loc('columnName')] = val
```